# Analyzer Results vs Leaks by Instruments : iPhone memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, xcode4, analyzer, xcode-instruments

I fixed memory leaks of my application using

**X-Code->run with performance tool -> leaks**

I submitted my application and later I **analyzed my code** attaching to device like **Build & Analyze** for device i got many **Potential Leaks** popped up when i pressed **Product** then **cmnd+shft+B**.

What is the difference between the two, was my fixing of leaks based on instruments wrong?

**Is it like some leaks pointed by analyzer may actually cause leaks which are not shown/caught by Performance tool?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the leaks performance tool it will let you know WHEN a leak actually happened.  Build & Analyze warns you of potential leaks that COULD happen while your program is running.

Your fixing leaks based on instruments was not wrong, but you should also carefully look into the leaks build & analyze tells you, as they could potentially leak when the program is actually running.